# How can I access to a file in a local directory project in visual studio

Tags: c#

I am developing an app in visual studio that reads from and writes to a file located in a directory in visual studio.

```
string creatureFile = @"\Resources\REGISTRADOS.DAT";
```

when I execute it i get a fileNotFoundException 
I hope for a help.

Comment: That line you showed us **CAN'T** throw a `fileNotFoundException`, please show the actual code you are using `creatureFile` with as a [edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27046858/edit)

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i use: 
               Func> ObtainCreatureList = ObtainCreatureListFromArray;

```
        string[] creatureNameArray = fileManager.ReadFromFile(creatureFile);

        IList<Creature> creatureList = ObtainCreatureList(creatureNameArray);

        var villianList = from creature in creatureList
                          where creature.Name.Contains(villianIdentifier)
                            select new Creature
                            {
                                Name = creature.Name  
                            };
        // Write Villians to VILLIANS.DAT file
        fileManager.WriteToFile(villiansFile, villianList.ToList());
        Console.WriteLine("Press one key");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

and the code of fileManager is
    public string[] ReadFromFile(string path)
        {
            return File.ReadAllLines(path);
        }

```
    public void WriteToFile(string path, IList<Creature> creatureCollection)
    {
        using (StreamWriter stream = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            foreach(var creature in creatureCollection)
            {
                stream.WriteLine(creature.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not post additional information as an answer - **edit** your original question to add/change things.